# How to connect react application to SQL application

Tags: reactjs

I would simply like to know how is the best route to connect a react application to SQL database?
I have read almost the whole internet at this point all I simply want to find out is how to link up a react front end to a SQL back end so that the data within the server can be displayed through the website.

Comment: You should create an API on a backend server. You should call this backend server from the React application. The backend server process the request call the sql server and handle back the result.

Comment: how would i create the API backend server ?

Comment: It depends what kind of programming language you prefer. And where is your database. I do not think I can teach you in a comment to create a service. But I can point you to a direction. If you prefer javascript you can create a nodejs backend with express. If you like Java I recommend Spring Boot for backend.

Comment: okay thankyou ! I have created a basic express react project. Now I just need to connect this to a mssql database.